# Web Application deployement works in Windows but fails in Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, apache-flex, tomcat7

I use Flex 4.6 with Java/BlazeDS.
I develop a web application and deploy it in Apache Tomcat.

The web application works well when deployed in Windows Platform.
But the same application fails when the application is deployed in Linux Platform.

When I request something from the server, I get the error message `/amf/messagebroker` not found.

In both cases I use the same portable Apache Tomcat 7.2.XX server and the same application WAR file.

Am I missing something here.
While googling I found out the `remoting-config.xml`, `server-config.xml` and `web.xml` configurations might be wrong. If it so, why didn't it fail in Windows.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Maybe you should paste the various files you think are relevant into the question by clicking "edit"

Comment: Maybe it could be related to case sentivity: Linux is case sentive for filenames, Windows is case insensitive. Check for the filename of `messagebroker`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with Apache Tomcat Web Server...

When I deployed the application in Linux using Apache Tomcat 7.0.19 the application did not work, but when the same application was deployed in Apache Tomcat 7.0.29 in Linux the application worked.